# Using Shiny Interactive Input to Filter NA values not working

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am working with a dataset with various variables (gender, residency, SES) and some of the cases of this dataset has `NA` values. Depending on the user input, I have been trying to use dplyr to filter out `NA` cases so that they are not graphed. However, the `filter(!is.na())`r function does not seem to be working as `NA` values are still graphed.

My code:

```
gender <- c("Male", "Female", NA)
residency <-c("InsideUS", "OutsideUS", NA)
category <- c("A", "B", NA)
SES <- c("Lower", "Middle", "Upper", NA)
choices <- c("gender", "residency", "SES")
variables <- c("SES")
cat<- c("category")


set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame( gender=as.factor(sample(gender, size=20, replace=TRUE)), 
              residency=as.factor(sample(residency, size=20, replace=TRUE)), 
              category=as.factor(sample(category, size=20, replace=TRUE)), 
              SES=as.factor(sample(SES, size=20, replace=TRUE)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "choiceDisplay1",
              label= "Please select an option",
              choices= c("Gender"="gender",
                         "Residency"="residency",
                         "Social Economic Status"="SES"),
              selected="gender")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #Target Market
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    df %>% filter_(!is.na(input$choiceDisplay1)) %>%
      group_by_(.choices=input$choiceDisplay1, .cat=c("category"), 
                 .variables=c("SES")) %>%
      summarize(n=n()) %>%
      ungroup()  %>% complete(.choices, .cat, .variables,
                          fill=list(n=0)) %>%
      group_by(.choices, .cat) %>%
      mutate(perc= n/sum(n))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I've tried variations such as `filter(is.na(.choices=choiceDisplay1))` but I get the following error: `supplied argument name '.choices' does not match 'x'`

Why isn't this dpylr function working?

Thank you!

Comment: This as nothing to do with Shiny - just use standard evaluation with dplyr. Try `df = data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 2)); col = "x"; filter_(df, !is.na(col))`. Doesn't work.

Comment: However `filter_(df, sprintf("!is.na(%s)", col))` does work. Or you can use `rlang` - plenty of documentation, vignettes, and questions on this site.